# Excel - How to add cells that has value on the same column but different rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know the actual standard on the following excel:

[image: Sample Table]

I need to sum the row 8 depending on the inputs on row 3 say for example, actual data on row 3 is until Wednesday (column D), the formula will add columns B, C, and D on row 8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS` with the criteria `<>` (not equal to null):
`=SUMIFS(B8:F8,B3:F3,"<>")`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Have a great day..

Comment: @JeffreyLegaspi You have to click on the green tick to mark my answer as the right answer.